Ionic Capacitor PendingIntent with unspecified mutability
does anyone know what it could be? When uploading to the Play Store, I'm receiving 4 warnings about PendingIntent with unspecified mutability.
I've already updated all my plugins, I'm on the latest version of Ionic and Capacitor, and I still have the problem.
The Android lint doesn't point out this error either, which would be:
Warning: Missing PendingIntent mutability flag [UnspecifiedImmutableFlag]
Could anyone give me some help?
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.9",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.3.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.9",
    "@angular/router": "^17.3.9",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/core": "^5.43.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/file-opener": "^5.43.0",
    "@capacitor/android": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/app": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/browser": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/clipboard": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/device": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/filesystem": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/push-notifications": "6.0.1",
    "@capacitor/splash-screen": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "^6.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "8.2.0",
    "@ionic/cli": "7.2.0",
    "capacitor-native-biometric": "^3.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": "^4.0.0",
    "date-fns": "3.6.0",
    "heic2any": "^0.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "ng-circle-progress": "^1.6.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.0",
    "simple-mask-money": "^3.0.1",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.4.8",
    "swiper": "^11.1.3",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "17.3.8",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "17.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "17.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "17.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "17.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "17.5.0",
    "@angular/cli": "17.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "^17.0.2",
    "@capacitor/cli": "6.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^11.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^48.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "5.4.5"
  },


I tried to update all the packages and debugging using the Android Studio lint as per its documentation and didn't get any error return in any of the libraries.


sounds like one of your plugins is causing the error. Go through each one and see which it is. I think it's this one: sweetalert2. remove it and build again and check. you shoulnt be using3rd party libs if ionic provides customizable popups component....
